# Universally Accessible Data Class for Android

Tags: java, android

I'm in need of a class that exists behind all of my other classes as a sort of overseer. It would contain Objects 'foo' and 'bar[]' that need to be created by one activity and accessed by others at a further point. I also need a listener to be attached to 'foo'.

My first thought was just a simple class (let's call it 'Overseer') with a few static methods and variables for easy setting/getting access from anywhere that implements the FooListener. However I don't think that would allow me to have a listener set to 'foo' because there would never be an instantiation of 'Overseer' to register the listener. ..right? (I may be too tired an not thinking clearly).

My second thought was to make 'Overseer' a little bit more advanced and actually construct an object from it in my main Activity while keeping the variables static. That would keep an instance of it in my main Activity, and also provide static access to its variables.

My final thought was to maybe sort of combine the two ideas into one and have no instance of 'Overseer' but within 'Overseer' add a FooListener to 'foo' using an Anonymous Class. When the setter for 'foo' is called is when the class would be defined and attached to 'foo'.

What would you suggest? What is the best way to go about doing this? I'm open to answers that have nothing to do with my original ideas.

**Update:** The `Application` class has everything that I need. Perfect for my needs. I see from my research that you must make sure that none of your variables go null when the Application process is killed and Android OS then creates a new one when restoring the user to the activity they left off on. So for anyone reading this, keep that in mind.

Comment: You need to extend `Application` class for your app and put all the universal logic there.

Comment: That's perfect! Never had looked into `Application` class before.